# How To Change An Association With A .jar File?

Tags: java, jar

So I changed the association with my .jar to associate with cmd and not java. So whenever I try to run an executable jar file or non-executable jar file, it always opens up cmd. Every time I change the file association back to java and save it, it automatically resets it back to associate with cmd. This is getting really annoying when trying to run executable jars. Please Help!

Comment: So you want to fix your file association in windows which is not really a Java programming question.  Which version of Windows do you have?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are questions about setting up a dev or runtime environment off topic now? Not trying to attack you, I really don't know :)

Comment: @owlstead More pointing out that if you want help setting up Windows, then picking tags or a forum for windows support would be a better idea.  The `[java]` tag is more likely to attract developers of Java and could explain why three people voted to close the question.  In any case, the answer is dependant on the version of Windows the OP is using.

Comment: im using windows 7. and sorry if it is off-topic, i am very sorry and im new to stackoverflow